# How to call function from within constructor of a struct in Julia?

Tags: function, methods, constructor, julia, blockchain

I'm a programmer with a C++ and Python background who recently stumbled upon Julia, and I really like what it has to offer. In order to become more familiar with both blockchain implementation and Julia at the same time, I'm being a little ambitious and am trying to create a basic implementation of a blockchain in Julia by converting the Python implementation posted by [Hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/learn-blockchains-by-building-one-117428612f46) (The author explains what each method is supposed to do better than I ever could).

However, I'm running into issues when creating the actual `Blockchain` struct. In order to create the genesis block, Hackernoon suggests I call the member function `new_block` in the constructor. So far, I haven't been able to figure out how to best replicate this in Julia. Here's what I have so far:

```
import JSON
import SHA

mutable struct Blockchain
    chain::Array{Dict{String, Any}}
    current_transactions::Array{String}
    block::Dict{String, Any}
    new_block::Function

    function Blockchain(chain::Array{Dict{String, Any}}, current::Array{String})    
        new(chain, current, new_block(previous_hash=1, proof=100)) 
        # ^issue calling function within the constructor here
    end
end
```

When I try to run my code, I get the following error:

`invalid redefinition of constant Blockchain`.

Here's the `new_block` function:

```
function new_block(proof::String, previous_hash::String=nothing)
    block = Dict(
    "index" => length(chain) + 1,
    "timestamp" => time(),
    "transactions" => current_transactions,
    "proof" => proof,
    "previous_hash" => previous_hash | hash(chain[end]),
    )
    current_transactions = []
    append!(chain, block)
    return block
end
```

Here are the rest of the functions I currently have:

```
function new_transaction(this::Blockchain, sender::String, recipient::String, amount::Int)
    
     transaction = Dict(
        "sender"=> sender,
        "recipient"=> recipient,
        "amount"=> amount,
     )

    append!(this.current_transactions, transaction)

    return length(this.chain) + 1
end

function hash(block::Blockchain)
    block_string = JSON.dumps(block, sort_keys=true).encode()
    return sha256(block_string).hexdigest()
end
```

I might have some misconceptions about how types/structs work in Julia; most of my information was obtained from third party websites along with the official documentation. Here are some of the sources I've been relying on:

- https://scls.gitbooks.io/ljthw/content/_chapters/06-ex3.html
- https://thenewphalls.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/understanding-object-oriented-programming-in-julia-part-1/
- https://juliabyexample.helpmanual.io/

Smarter/more efficient ways of trying to accomplish what I am would be immensely appreciated.

## Edit:

Here are some of the changes I've made, based on given suggestions:

```
struct Blockchain
    chain::Array{Dict{String, Any}}
    current_transactions::Array{String}

    function Blockchain(chain::Array{Dict{String, Any}}, current::Array{String})    
        new(chain, current)
    end
end

function new_block!(this::Blockchain, proof::Int, previous_hash::Int=nothing)
    block = Dict(
    "index" => length(this.chain) + 1,
    "timestamp" => time(),
    "transactions" => this.current_transactions,
    "proof" => proof,
    )
    if previous_hash == nothing
        block["previous_hash"] = hash(this.chain[end])
    else
        block["previous_hash"] = previous_hash
    end

    this.current_transactions = []
    append!(this.chain, block)
    return this
end
```

I realized that the `block` attribute was useless, as it only existed to be added to the `chain`, so I removed it.

Additionally, here is an alternate `Blockchain` definition without the inner constructor:

```
struct Blockchain
    chain::Array{Dict{String, Any}}
    current_transactions::Array{String}
    
    Blockchain(x::Array{Dict{String, Any}}, y::Array{String}) = new(x, y)
end
```

Comment: Hi Victor. First the error message `invalid redefinition of constant Blockchain` isn't related to your `new_block` function stuff at all. It's just that you can't redefine a type (struct) in Julia. Once it's defined you can't change it anymore.

Comment: The error that you really get when calling your constructor `Blockchain(chain, current)` is `ERROR: UndefVarError: new_block not defined` which makes perfect sense. I'd suggest to not put the `new_block` function into the struct at all. Typically in Julia you put "attributes" into the struct and functions separately.

Comment: So your `new_block` should simply take a `Blockchain` object as first argument. You can than access and modify fields of this `Blockchain`.

Comment: That makes sense. Does that mean that the constructor should go outside of the `struct` along with `new_block`?

Comment: @victor-alves, constructor *can* stay within the `struct` definition. however, [inner constructors](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/constructors/#Inner-Constructor-Methods-1) will have another effect on your code, *i.e.*, no default constructor will be generated by Julia's compiler. Basically, your original problem has *nothing* to do with your constructor, nor `new_block`. You cannot redefine the type, as the error already suggests. Then, when you solve that problem, you will face another one because you are trying to call part of an object which is to be created (not yet done)

Comment: @victor-alves, then, when you fix the constructor problem, you will see the problems I have summarized below in the answer you have delegated. In other words, your definition of `new_block` needs to be redefined accordingly.

Comment: The inner constructor is exactly what Julia will provide you with, and hence, _not_ needed. Try removing the `function ... end` part and creating a variable with `Blockchain([Dict("x"=>5)], ["y"])`. `new_block` modifies `this`, and hence, should be called `new_block!`. `previous_hash` should _not_ be `Int`, rather something meaningful to be or'ed (`|`) with `hash`. `this` does _not_ have any member called `hash`. `append!` returns `this.chain` after appending `block`, and this will be the return value of `new_block`. I would instead `return block` or `return this` after `append!(...)`.

Comment: Your modification should not compile and run properly with `new_block` on 2 parameters as you are trying to `|` a `Void` with some `hash`. Well, in fact, `this.hash` should _not_ compile, either. Please make sure you have [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Apologies for such a mess, I'll be much more careful the next time I post a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER.** This may *not* necessarily be an answer to your question. But I wanted to post it as an answer, as a comment does *not* allow me to express the below that easily.

```
mutable struct Blockchain
    chain::Array{Dict{String, Any}}
    current_transactions::Array{String}
    block::Dict{String, Any}
    new_block::Function

    function Blockchain(chain::Array{Dict{String, Any}}, current::Array{String})    
        new(chain, current, new_block(previous_hash=1, proof=100)) 
        # ^issue calling function within the constructor here
    end
end
```

Here, I assume that you are trying to *add* some member function functionality to your `struct`, as you have already stated that you are coming from a `C++` background. However, this is not Julian. In Julia, as @crstnbr has already suggested, we need to define global functions that act on objects. The convention is that you add `!` at the end of the function to indicate that the function will be changing *at least* one of its arguments.

Then, by checking the definition of your `new_block`:

```
function new_block(proof::String, previous_hash::String=nothing)
    block = Dict(
    "index" => length(chain) + 1, # which chain?
    "timestamp" => time(),
    "transactions" => current_transactions, # which current_transactions?
    "proof" => proof,
    "previous_hash" => previous_hash | hash(chain[end]), # which chain?
    )
    current_transactions = []
    append!(chain, block) # which chain?
    return block
end
```

I notice a couple of serious mistakes. First, there are some undefined variables that you try to use such as `chain` and `current_transactions`. I assume, again from `C++`, you have thought that `new_block` would be a member function of `Blockchain`, and hence, could *see* its `chain` member variable. This is *not* how `Julia` works. Second problem is how you try to call `new_block`:

```
new_block(previous_hash=1, proof=100)
```

This call is *totally* wrong. The above call notation relies on [keyword arguments](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/functions/#Keyword-Arguments-1); however, your function definition *only* has positional arguments. To be able to support keyword arguments, you need to change your function definition to read as below:

```
function new_block(; proof::String, previous_hash::String=nothing)
  #                ^ note the semi-colon here
  # ...
end
```

And last, you define `proof` and `previous_hash` to be of type `String`, but call them with `1`, `100` and `nothing`, which are of type `Int`, `Int` and `Void`.

I could not understand your design choice for the Blockchain application in your mind, but I strongly suggest that you should go step-by-step with simpler examples to learn the language. For instance, if you just try the below examples, you will understand how type annotations work in Julia:

```
Main> f(s::String = nothing) = s
f (generic function with 2 methods)

Main> f()
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching f(::Void)
Closest candidates are:
  f(::String) at none:1
  f() at none:1
Stacktrace:
 [1] f() at ./none:1
 [2] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235

Main> g(s::String) = s
g (generic function with 1 method)

Main> g(100)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching g(::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  g(::String) at none:1
Stacktrace:
 [1] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235

Main> h1(var1 = 1, var2 = 100) = var1 + var2
h1 (generic function with 3 methods)

Main> h1(var2 = 5, var1 = 6)
ERROR: function h1 does not accept keyword arguments
Stacktrace:
 [1] kwfunc(::Any) at ./boot.jl:237
 [2] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:235
```

One last comment is that as far as I can see from your example, you do not need [`mutable struct`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#Mutable-Composite-Types-1). `struct` should simply help you with your design --- you can still add to/modify its `chain`, `current_transactions` and `block` variables. Check, again, the simpler example below:

```
Main> struct MyType
         a::Vector{Float64}
       end

Main> m = MyType([1,2,3]);

Main> append!(m.a, 4);

Main> m
MyType([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
```

You can think of `MyType`'s `a` variable, in the above example, as being `double * const a` in `C++` terms. You are *not* allowed to change `a` to point to a different memory location, but you can modify the memory location pointed-to by `a`.

In short, you should *definitely* try to learn the language from the official documentation step-by-step, and post questions here involving *really* minimal examples. Your example is convoluted in that sense.

Comment: Thank you for all of this information! It definitely seems like I bit off more than I could chew with this sort of project, so I think I'll have to take a closer look at the documentation, as you suggested.

Comment: Yours was the single most useful answer I've read about Julia on stackoverflow!

Comment: Thank you, @PatrickT, for your kind words/feedback. I will try to answer more with this motivation in mind.